# Can we save IE console from developer tools to a file?

Tags: internet-explorer, console, reporting, developer-tools

We have a full AJAX website to debug.
The development network and host are really different than our client.

So if we try to access to the platform we don't have any problem
The client can work too but regularly stuck on loading state for undefined reason.

This is why we need to know if is there any possibility to background log console or network data from IE (9 or 11) Developer Tools into a file that we could retrieve latter.

Is there, perhaps, a plugin or application to do the same job instead of native functionality ?

PS: JFiddler is a good tool to log network but don't want to use https decryption on production environment

Comment: From now the solution were catch http errors and code, aggregate an errors table and report it on an sql server when connexion retrieved back. This was nice to report some server issues to our provider.

Answer (score 8):

I'm a little late but just had this issue and this was the question that came up on my search. I'll add my solution here for future users.

If you just need to save the contents of the IE Developer Tools log you can do it by right-clicking on the contents of the log and select "Copy All". Then paste into a text editor and save. Chrome has a button for this, but if your requirement is IE then this is all I could find.

Comment: Yes, I found this way works only on dev environment. In my case we wanted to retrieve error logs from final users.

Answer (score 1):

You can over-write console.log function to achieve the desired behavior.

```
console.log = function(msg){alert(msg); }
console.log('hi');
```

there is no easy way of writing to file so you need to send data to your server and save there.